# building a Backbone+requireJS website into one JS file (including HTML) using r.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs

I am trying to use r.js for the first time.

I downloaded the [todoMVC](https://github.com/addyosmani/todomvc) github project.

I am interested in the dependency-examples/backbone_require architecture.

how do i make the entire project one JS file (including the templates).

btw,
our final goal is to make a chrome extension.
but as i am researching into requireJS i would like to know how to minify the entire dependency tree also for web development purposes.

thanks

Comment: if you are going to build chrome extension, why would you want to minify your JS? it's sitting there in the browser on user's file system, no http requests are happening, you distribute it as a package.

Comment: you might be right. do you recommend keeping requireJS? i am studying the requireJS approach and anyhow i would like to know how to minify the entire dependency tree. furthermore, i am not sure chrome extensions allow dynamic loading of html templates (do they)?

Comment: HTML templates, in context of JS application are just JavaScript functions (when precompiled), so I don't see why chrome extensions wouldn't let you load them. I definitely recommend keeping RequireJS, my opinion is that it's the best AMD loader out there.

Comment: did you follow http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html? did something particular not work for you?